# Portal to a node outside root react element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fullscreen, portal

I need to draw react (MUI) elements above fullscreen element (map in fullscreen mode) that is created dynamically in a body element.

I've managed to do so by creating a div directly in body with the following style:

```
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
```

The contents of this div appear above the map in fullscreen mode.

The map in fullscreen mode also dynamically creates its element in body.

But because this element is outside my map wrapper component and it is even outside react root node - I do not know how can I render mui components there.

I'm aware of Portal functionality but it needs a ref to the destination div.

How can I obtain this ref if the div is outside react root and is created dynamically or statically in index.html?

Comment: ok if another root element is placed in the index.html next to the react root you can just call `document.getElementById` on it to get the ref and specify that to the portal to render stuff into that div, but if you want elements to just be at the top level could you have a top level component that just creates a context or something that stores a list of divs somehow? like managing it still within the react root just near the top seems like a better idea.

Comment: *better if you need dynamic, if you just need to be able to make a portal to one div and the thing putting content there is definitely only going to have one instance rendering then using a portal is fine. but any more complicated than that and you will want to probably use a context with 'add/remove tree' kinds of methods.

Comment: A top level component in a root is also doing its job. And yes it is possible (I hope) to create a top level component with a context and to pass necessary refs to map, but because of this map becomes not independant component anymore. It's a little drawback as of me. If a map could do everything dynamic it is a better option.
But how can I pass the result of getElementById to a ref? Are the types compatible?

Comment: Create a state, `const [container, setContainer] = useState();` that will hold the element. Now, create a `useEffect(()=>{ if(!container){ setContainer(document.body); },[container]);` the dependency in the useEffect is important. Now you can use the container(which holds the body element) in the `createPortal(<Some component/>, container);`

Comment: Try the above approach to use the portal

Comment: Thank you Tadhg and John. I'll try this.
John can you please clarify the dependancy role? Can not catch it.

Comment: You're right, you don't need that. Halfway writing the comment I confused with a similar approach but when using a useRef() where an element hasn't been rendered yet and you have an empty ref. But in your case the body always exist. Sorry for the unnecessary headache I may have caused.

Comment: Now I understand. There are two kind of portals react-portals and mui-portals. The one that require ref is the mui portal. React portal can be used with a plain DOM node.